# Processing form input in a Joomla component

Tags: joomla

I am creating a Joomla component and one of the pages contains a form with a text input for an email address.
When a `<` character is typed in the input field, that character and everything after is not showing up in the input.
I tried `$_POST['field']` and `JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('field')`
I also tried alternatives for `getCmd` like `getVar`, `getString`, etc. but no success.

E.g. `John Doe <j.doe@mail.com>` returns only John Doe.

When the `<` is left out, like `John Doe j.doe@mail.com>` the value is coming in correctly.
What can I do to also have the < character in the posted variable?

BTW. I had to use & lt; in this question to display it as I want it. This form suffers from the same problem!!

Comment: Which version of Joomla? Also show your XML for the form and the PHP?

Answer (score 0):

The default text filter trims html from the input for your field. You should set the property

```
filter="raw"
```

in your form's manifest (xml) file, and then use `getRaw()` to retrieve the value.  getCmd removes the non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Oops. That is a lot unknown in two sentences.
This is my first component and I read the basic introduction.
In one of the tasks I echo a form in plain html. My problem is with the posted text input. How does this relate to my components xml file? Do I have to add something like <form name="myform"> filter="raw" </form> behind the files section?

Comment: Ok, I thought the form was generated by Joomla.  Then you have no automatic filtering set, you just need to use getRaw() and you should get the value as inserted

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to set the filtering that you want when you grab the input. Otherwise, you will get some heavy filtering. (Typically, I will also lose `@` symbols.)

Replace this line:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('field');
```

with this line:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->input->getRaw('field');
```

The name after the `get` part of the function is the filtering that you will use. `Cmd` strips everything but alphanumeric characters and `.`, `-`, and `_`. `String` will run through the html clean tags feature of joomla and depending on your settings will clean out `<>`. (That usually doesn't happen for me, but my settings are generally pretty open to the point of no filtering on super admins and such.

`getRaw` should definitely work, but note that there is no filtering at all, which can open security holes in your application.